# android app's height/width is different in emulator than on device

Tags: android

I am running a couple of imageviews and a listview in an activity in my app. The display looks perfect in the emulator, which basically displays a short string, two small images at the top and then the rest of the screen consisting of the listview, but when I put it on my device (EVO3D) the listview is cutoff. In fact the width even seems slightly off.

Here is the layout.xml file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView android:text="@string/showRunList_name" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/editText1">
</TextView>

<ImageView android:contentDescription="@string/auxLogo" 
android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:src="@drawable/logo_small" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center">
</ImageView>

<ImageView android:contentDescription="@string/auxPhone" 
 android:id="@+id/imageView2" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/phone" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
</ImageView>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/android:empty"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/main_no_items"/>

<ListView
android:id="@+id/android:list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="bottom|right"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Create emulators with same resolution as your device and test it.

Comment: Thank you, I read this article today. I also created an emulator that is 540x960 @256dpi. I've been able to duplicate the issue in this new AVD and am working to try to get it to display the way I want. It's worth mentioning that my main activity is also doing this not just the one I listed above.

Comment: Okay, I got it to work my defining a min. SDK in my manifest file;
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Let me list out few points to take care off:

1. You need to read this article: [**`Supporting Multiple Screens`**](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).
2. As you have described, image views are at top and the rest of the screen is covered by ListView, but you have defined android:layout_height="wrap_content" in parent , instead it should be android:layout_height="fill_parent" so it will be having full screen height.
3. To make ListView to cover, rest of the screen, define `android:layout_height="match_parent"` or **`android:layout_weight="1"`**.
4. Use **`dp`** or **`dip`** instead of fixed size PX for defining measurements like height/width.
5. Use **`sp`** (Scaled point) while defining font-size.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it still is displaying the same way on my device. I've created multiple emulators and it looks fine on them but my device appears to be cutting off the entire bottom 1/3 of the page. It is also doing this on my other activity as well.

Comment: Give me a rough sketch of the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add multiscreen support properties into config files and also create different images as per the standard if you want to support multiscreen. Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

The resolution/aspect of your emulator is different than the device.  The EVO3D has a resolution of 540x960.  Your emulator is probably either HVGA (320x480) or WVGA (480x800).  This slight variation causes the visible portion of your layout to shift somewhat.

Keep in mind your application will encounter many more device resolution/aspect ratio differences out in the market, so it should react appropriately to these changes.

HTH